# Bing map integration in Angular 5

Tags: angular5, bing-maps

I tried to implement bing map in angular 4. I used angular-map package but it throws Microsoft reference issue. Please see the below code and share the example

```html
import { Component,OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { BingMapsLoader } from '../../shared/services/map-loader-service';

@Component({
  selector: 'pm-map',
  template: `
  <app-bing-map *ngIf='mapReady'></app-bing-map>`
})

export class DeviceMapComponent implements OnInit{
  mapReady = false;
      constructor() {
          BingMapsLoader.load()
              .then(res => {
                  console.log('BingMapsLoader.load.then', res);
                  this.mapReady = true;
          });
      }
      ngOnInit() {
        if (typeof Microsoft !== 'undefined') {
            console.log('BingMapComponent.ngOnInit');
            this.map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapId'),{
              credentials: 'Your Bing Maps Key Here',
          });
        }
      }   
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey Amit, can you tell me which npm library have you used? I am using ng2-bingmaps and I'm getting some issues. Please help me out!

Comment: Tell me the issue that you are facing.
I used https://github.com/infusion-code/angular-maps

Comment: I was trying to implement the same. I needed to see ur HTML code.

Comment: <app-bing-map *ngIf='mapReady'></app-bing-map>
THis is only need to bind html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import { } from "bingmaps/scripts/MicrosoftMaps/Microsoft.Maps.All"
```

This needs to be imports to get access of Microsoft reference.