# Bingmap integration in Angular 6 using angular-map package

Tags: angular, typescript, bing-maps

i am trying to implement bingmap in angular 6 using "angular-map" npm packages for that i have [refer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-maps) also [referred](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50155210/bing-map-integration-in-angular-5)
problem statement: not created "bingmaps" folder in node_modules

app.module.ts

```
/// <reference path="node_modules/bingmaps/types/MicrosoftMaps/Microsoft.Maps.All.d.ts" />
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { MapModule, MapAPILoader, BingMapAPILoaderConfig, BingMapAPILoader, WindowRef, DocumentRef, MapServiceFactory, BingMapServiceFactory } from "angular-maps";
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
```

error:

> ERROR in ./node_modules/angular-maps/fesm5/angular-maps.js
>       Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'bingmaps' in 'D:\bingmap\bingmap\node_modules\angular-maps\fesm5'
>       i ｢wdm｣: Failed to compile.
>       ERROR in src/app/app.module.ts(1,23): error TS6053: File 'D:/bingmap/bingmap/src/app/node_modules/bingmaps/types/MicrosoftMaps/Microsoft.Maps.All.d.ts'
>   not found.

also installed `npm install --save @types/bingmaps`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just tested both locally & on stackblitz and realized that there are some library dependencies you have to install in order to make angular-maps work. I received the same error as you but once I installed the libraries the error was gone.

Your package.json should contain these libraries:

```
"@types/bingmaps": "0.0.1",
"angular-maps": "^6.0.1",
"async": "^2.5.0",
"bingmaps": "^2.0.3",
"core-js": "^2.5.4",
"font-awesome": "^4.6.3",
"json-loader": "^0.5.7",
```

so you need to install them

```
npm install --save angular-maps
npm install --save bingmaps
npm install --save @types/bingmaps
npm install --save async@2.5.0
npm install --save json-loader
```

I included font-awesome as external link in index.html:

```
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

On app.module.ts include this as well as on app.component.ts:

```
import {
    MapModule,
    MapAPILoader,
    MarkerTypeId,
    IMapOptions,
    IBox,
    IMarkerIconInfo,
    WindowRef,
    DocumentRef,
    MapServiceFactory,
    BingMapAPILoaderConfig,
    BingMapAPILoader,
    GoogleMapAPILoader,
    GoogleMapAPILoaderConfig
} from 'angular-maps';
```

If you check also on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yvqvga) you can see on dependencies which extra libraries are used

Comment: working fine ......could you suggest me to how I zoom on one particular area and make it as the different color

Comment: That is a different topic. You need to post it as a new question.

Comment: i have posted it here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51999520/draw-circle-arround-latitude-and-longitude-angular-bingmap

Comment: Thanks for your effort .it solved my issue ...keep doing illumination @kboul