# angular-maps integration in angular 6

Tags: angular, maps, bing-maps

I am trying to add bing-maps in my project. I am using angular 6.

[I have followed the steps listed here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-maps), starting from installation.
I got some errors which are solved now by [the solution in here from stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51987104/bingmap-integration-in-angular-6-using-angular-map-package?rq=1).
[referring to this link again](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-maps) in 2nd step I get the following error:

> ReferenceError: provide is not defined

it comes from the code below:

```
provide: MapAPILoader,
deps: [],
useFactory: MapServiceProviderFactory
```

It would be great if some one can help me.
Thanks.
S.O.

Edit:
app.module.ts:

```
import {
  BrowserModule
} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {
  NgModule
} from '@angular/core';

import {
  AppComponent
} from './app.component';


// bing STart==========================================
/// <reference path="node_modules/bingmaps/types/MicrosoftMaps/Microsoft.Maps.All.d.ts" />
import {
  MapModule,
  MapAPILoader,
  MarkerTypeId,
  IMapOptions,
  IBox,
  IMarkerIconInfo,
  WindowRef,
  DocumentRef,
  MapServiceFactory,
  BingMapAPILoaderConfig,
  BingMapAPILoader,
  GoogleMapAPILoader,
  GoogleMapAPILoaderConfig
} from 'angular-maps';
// bing End============================================

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    MapModule.forRoot()
  ],
  providers: [
    provide: MapAPILoader,
    deps: [],
    useFactory: MapServiceProviderFactory
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have it inside Provider array,

```
providers: [
    { provide: MapAPILoader}
  ]
```

Comment: I have it inside that:

Comment: https://github.com/hoveytechllc/angular-maps-demo/blob/971b062f674b3e256e0820b3907a287aa5f401d7/src/app/app.module.ts